# Change another field of value when value in input has been changed jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form (part of jconfirm content) has an input field. User can change the input value and the offline amount needs to be updated according to the calculation in updateOfflineAmount() based on the changed value of balance amount. Right now the offline amount is not being updated after the input field which is the balance amount has been altered.

```
$.confirm({
    title:'',
    content:'<form action="" class="formName">' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<div id="account_balance">account balance: $'+account_balance+'</div>' +
        '<div id="total_amount">total amount: $'+total_amount+'</div>' +
        '<div id="balance_amount">balance amount: <input type="number" id="balance_amount" name="balance_amount" value='+balance_amount+'></div>'+
        '<div id="offline_amount">offline amount: $'+offline_amount+'</div>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</form>'
});

function updateOfflineAmount(){
    var balance_amount_tmp=$('#balance_amount').val();
    offline_amount=total_amount-balance_amount_tmp;
    $("#offline_amount").val(offline_amount);
}

$('body').on('change','#balance_amount',function() {
    updateOfflineAmount();
});
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML and the full JavaScript please? We don't see your variables, or the actual markup

Comment: @JackBashford the <div> is not in HTML, it is in jquery confirm modal and that is all my full JS

Comment: But what is this variable `account_balance`? There's no declaration for it anywhere.

Comment: it gets the value of data in a success:function(data) of AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you double `ID` and mix between `html()` and `val()`, use `parseInt()` to get interger from html and it better to use `input` event

```js
var account_balance = 999,
  total_amount = 666,
  balance_amount = 0,
  offline_amount = 0,
  myForm = '<form action="" class="formName">' +
  '<div class="form-group">' +
  '<div id="account_balance">account balance: $<span id="total_amount">' + account_balance + '</span></div>' +
  '<div>total amount: $' + total_amount + '</div>' +
  '<div>balance amount: <input type="number" id="balance_amount" name="balance_amount" value=' + balance_amount + '></div>' +
  '<div>offline amount: $<span id="offline_amount">' + offline_amount + '</span></div>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</form>'
$('body').html(myForm);

function updateOfflineAmount() {
  var balance_amount_tmp = $('#balance_amount').val(),
    total_amount = parseInt($('#total_amount').html());
  $('#balance_amount').val(balance_amount_tmp);
  offline_amount = total_amount - balance_amount_tmp;
  $("#offline_amount").html(offline_amount);
}

$('#balance_amount').on('input', function() {
  updateOfflineAmount();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: $('#balance_amount').val(balance_amount_tmp); is this line doing the update job ?

Comment: may i know after the user has changed the value in the input field, how could i update it as the final value will be passed to back-end

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to use `on()` method.you can use like

```
$('body').on('change','#balance_amount', function() {
    updateOfflineAmount();
});
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: now it enters the function but still the offline amount is not being updated after the value of input field has been changed

Answer (score 0):

in script tag you add

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // jQuery methods go here... or all js and jquery code here 

});
```

jquery starting syntax

Comment: This is not a relevant answer.